# Spring Data JPA transaction

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have three classes which are related to each other like

- `Product` -oneToMany-> `ProductRevision`
- `ProductRevision` -oneToMany-> `ProductDateVarient`

I have used following `cascadeType` for all this entities

**Product:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Set<ProductRevision> productRevisions;
```

**Product Revision:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productRevision", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Set<ProductDateVariant> productDateVariants ;
//save Product data with Populated values for ProductRevision and  ProductDateVarient
productRepository.save(product);
```

When I try to save `Product` data with invalid data for `ProductDateVarient`, it gives exception for it but saves data of `ProductRevision`. I think it should be transaction so that when exception occurs the `ProductRevision` data would not get saved. What am I missing?

Comment: see the exception stacktrace, your question is incomplete to get an answer

Comment: When you get an exception, never just say "it gives exception". The error message contains important information about what's wrong. Read it and try to understand it. Post the exact error message in your question, so that others can help you understand what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Jesper, vels4j I am getting exception is not issue, it is due to constraint violation, my concern is, if exception occurs in particular transaction now in this case during inserting data in ProductDateVarient table it should not insert data in Product Revision, is it right ? if yes, it is not happening. It is inserting data in Product Revision table and throwing exception during inserting data in Product Date varient which is due to constraint violation.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code inside a transaction?  Can you post a full working sample that demonstrates how changes due to individual SQL statements are getting saved despite a transaction?